# How discover if a DLL runs in the context of a windows service?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, service, process

I am writing a DLL which may run in the context of a service and may be loaded into a standard  win32 process. How can I detect whether it is running in the context of a service or in the context of a standard win32 process ?

Comment: DLLs that try to do clever things by magic tend to fail badly later. What will you do differently based on what context you're in? It would be better to let the caller explicitly configure the DLL into an appropriate mode.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: A service *is* a standard Win32 process. Please describe the problem you're *really* hoping to solve with this question.

Comment: I am running on windows vista/7/8. Unfortunately I can't change the interfaces to my DLL to allow the caller to specify if it is running in the context of a service. I need to know if I should attempt GUI code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx), introduced in Vista, Windows Services run in session 0. To determine if the process is executing in session 0 you could use [ProcessIdToSessionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
DWORD session_id;
if (ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &session_id))
{
    std::cout << "session_id=" << session_id << "\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed : " << GetLastError() << "\n";
}
```

In relation to your comment regarding GUI, to quote directly from the linked document:

> Because Session 0 is no longer a user session, services that are running in Session 0 do not have access to the video driver. This means that any attempt that a service makes to render graphics fails.